# align a widget to start and end instead of left and right

Tags: flutter

I've translated an app to the Arabic language, and everything is looking great, there is one problem with this widget Align:

```
return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
              child: textField,
            ),
            elevation: 4.0,
          ),
        ),
        if (symbol != null)
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(0.95, -0.9),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                child: Text(
                  symbol!,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 13.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
```

it's set to a specific position where I want to make respond to LTR & RTL 
here is an example of how it looks on LTR languages:
[image]
And here's how it looks on RTL languages, the arrow indicates where it should be:
[image]

Comment: `AlignmentDirectional` maybe? the docs say: *"An offset that's expressed as a fraction of a Size, but whose horizontal component is dependent on the writing direction.

This can be used to indicate an offset from the left in TextDirection.ltr text and an offset from the right in TextDirection.rtl text without having to be aware of the current text direction."*

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to use the AlignmentDirectional Widget instead of the Alignment, it supports the properties `topStart`,`topEnd`, and more

```dart
Align(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topLeft,should change
        child: Card(
              ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the alignment property to be set as topLeft

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
          child: textField,
        ),
        elevation: 4.0,
      ),
    ),
    if (symbol != null)
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft, // this is the line that you should change
        child: Card(
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text(
              symbol!,
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 13.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
      ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: The alignment widget doesn't have this property, but AlignmentDirctional does, but thank you!

Comment: I solved with the AlignmentDirectional widget